# Java split String that start with space

Tags: java, string, split

I know how to split a string by space as the following:

```
String[] array = string.split(" ");
```

This works great until I try to split string that starts with a space like

" I like apple"

The result looks something like this:

{"", "I", "like", "apple"}

How can I split the string so it only keeps strings that is not empty?

Comment: Trim the string first.

Comment: `.trim()` would work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `string.trim()`and then `string.split(" ")`. The `trim()` method removes spaces before the first non-space-character and after the last non-space-character.

Answer (score 1):

To remove leading and trailing spaces, you can use `.trim()`.

```
String[] array = string.trim().split(" ");
```